# I want to ROOT Ravoz Z8 (New Brand)

Tags: rooting, 9.0-pie

First of I already done my research about how to root without TWRP/Custom Recovery since my phone brand is new which is RAVOZ.

Now i finally found a solution which is to root without TWRP/CR but there is a problem.

On MAGISK you can root your phone without it, but it needs a ‘Stock boot image‘ but i can't find it anywhere on website. Please somebody help me to root my phone.

Phone Model: **RAVOZ Z8**
Android Ver: **9**

Comment: https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/amazing-temp-root-mediatek-armv8-t3922213/post79626434